# How to view the values of Swift float2, float3, float4, etc in XCode debugger?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, debugging

I am always hampered in debugging by the inability of XCode to display the values contained in the float3 and like types.  I always have to go in, put down some print statements, and then recompile.  And this is especially painful when I am trying to track where in a series of calculations a number is going wrong.

How do you view the values of these variables in XCode?  (and why doesn't Apple fix this issue...)

Thanks

Comment: It's fixed in Xcode 10, coming soon to a release near you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding extensions for those types to your code:

```
extension float3: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "x: \(self.x)\ny: \(self.y)\nz: \(self.z)"
    }
}
extension float4: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "x: \(self.x)\ny: \(self.y)\nz: \(self.z)\nw: \(self.w)"
    }
}

var aFloat3 = float3(x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0)
var aFloat4 = float4(x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0, w: 4.0)

print (aFloat3)
print (aFloat4)
```

Comment: Thanks -- but that just modifies the way they are printed, does it not?  I don't have any problem printing the values with print().  The problem is when I am debugging, stepping through and trying to view the values in the debugger -- by hovering the cursor or looking in the variable view.  It will not print the values -- I open the disclosure triangle and it just shows '_vector'.

Comment: Once you've added the extensions to your code you can type `e print(aFloat3)` in the debugger (where `e` is short for `expression`) and the debugger will use your description computed property to display the value. Adding `CustomStringConvertible` conformance is very useful in debugging.

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I can tell, this doesn't do anything besides format the printout in a custom way.  I can already just stop and type 'po <variable>' in the debugger console to see the printout, without extensions.  I was just hoping there was a way to look at variables by hovering or using the *variables view* window, like I do with every other type of normal variable.  Supposedly you can do it in XCode 10, so that will be nice.